# Adding up dice rolls with constraints

Tags: java

I have written the below code which generates 4 random, whole integer values between 1 and 6 and then saves the sum of the 3 largest values. It generates a total of 6 values this way, displays the total along with all 6 values once finished.

- The order in which each value was generated must be preserved.
- The total of all 6 values must be at least 75 or above.
- At least 2 of the values must be 15 or more.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    static boolean goodRoll = false;


    public static int genAttribute() {

        Random dice = new Random();
        int[] sumArray = {dice.nextInt(6) + 1, dice.nextInt(6) + 1, dice.nextInt(6) + 1, dice.nextInt(6) + 1};
        for (int num : sumArray) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }


        int first = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int firstIndex = -1;
        int second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int secondIndex = -1;
        int third = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


        for (int i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
            int num = sumArray[i];
            if (num > first) {
                first = num;
                firstIndex = i;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
            int num = sumArray[i];
            if (num > second && num <= first && i != firstIndex) {
                second = num;
                secondIndex = i;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
            int num = sumArray[i];
            if (num > third && num <= second && i != secondIndex && i != firstIndex) {
                third = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(first + " " + second + " " + third);

        return first + second + third;

    }

    public static boolean checkFinalArray(int[] checkArray) {
        int fifteenCount = 0;
        for (int z : checkArray) {
            if (z >= 15) {
                fifteenCount++;
            }
        }

        return (fifteenCount >= 2 && Arrays.stream(checkArray).sum() >= 75);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (!goodRoll) {
            int[] finalArray;
            finalArray = new int[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
                finalArray[i] = genAttribute();
            }

            if (checkFinalArray(finalArray)) {
                System.out.println("sum: " + Arrays.stream(finalArray).sum());
                // Enhanced for to print each die
                for (int x : finalArray) {
                    System.out.println(x);


                }
                goodRoll = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can this be more efficiently written?

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: (Down-voters please comment.)

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. How did you check this code does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: I have optimised from O(nlogn) to above .Please check and also can anyone help to convert it into TestNG so that no main method is required.

Comment: Can you please motivate why *efficiency* would be a concern?

Comment: To improve the time and space complexity of this code.

Answer (score 2):

- [Document your code. In the code.](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)
- Be sure you got the specification right.
  Very helpful here is giving *test* serious consideration early on.
  • testing `order in which each value was generated must be preserved`
   looks a nightmare

  One way to present the approach coded:
  1) generate six sums
  2) if this sextuple is not admissible, start over
  *Alternatives*:
  2b) while sextuple is not admissible, delete oldest sum and append a new one
    This still results in six sums generated in a row.
  2c) while sextuple is not admissible, delete smallest sum and append a new one
    This still preserves `the order in which each value was generated`
    - but it skews the distribution.
  **But:** What if the ***real*** requirement was
  *Generate* six pseudo-random values with a distribution identical to the one from a procedure as sketched, *with **utmost efficiency***
  (You'd have to define *efficiency*.)
- Name things for what they can/will be used for. Difficult to guess for (`test`,) `genAttribute()`, `checkFinalArray()`
- Parametrise where it does not add effort
  What if you next wanted seven values each from five rolls of tetrahedral dice, three over a threshold of eleven and a total of at least 42?
- sometimes it pays to take a step back and try to look at the requirements specification from a different angle:
  The sum of the three largest values out of four may seem to require identifying those three values.
  From a distance, it looks like the total minus the minimum.

I started putting in writing what I think should do:

```
   /** @param <code>nSums</code> count of sums to return
    *  @param <code>nDraws</code> count of summands for each sum
    *  @param <code>from</code> lower bound for summands
    *  @param <code>to_inclusive</code> upper bound for summands
    *  @param <code>threshold</code> for "big enough"
    *  @param <code>requiredCount</code> count of sums required to be
    *                                                   "big enough"
    *  @param <code>lowestTotal</code> total to reach
    *
    *  @return <code>nSums</code> of <code>nDraws</code> values each
    *   but the smallest among those
    *   - <em>if</em><br/>
    *    - at least <code>requiredCount</code> 
    *               sums reach <code>threshold</code> <em>and</em><br/>
    *    - the total is <code>lowestTotal</code>, at least */
    public static int[]
    sufficientTopSums(int nSums, int nDraws, int from, int to_inclusive,
        int threshold, int requiredCount, int lowestTotal) {
        // Start with a queue filled with very negative values
        // keep a total and a count of sufficiently high sums

        // check int range suffices
        assert((long)(nDraws - 1) * to_inclusive < Integer.MAX_VALUE / nSums);
        final int veryNegative = Integer.MIN_VALUE/nDraws;
        Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>(Collections.nCopies(
            nSums, veryNegative));
        for (int total = veryNegative * nSums, sufficient = 0 ; ; ) {
            int replaced = q.remove();
            // account for value removed
            total -= replaced;
            if (threshold <= replaced)
                sufficient--;
            // generate & keep new sum
            int sum = sumIgnoringMin(nDraws, from, to_inclusive);
            q.add(sum);
            // account for new value
            if (threshold <= sum)
                sufficient++;
            if (lowestTotal <= (total += sum)
                && requiredCount <= sufficient)
                return q.stream().mapToInt(x->x).toArray();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
            sufficientTopSums(6, 4, 1, 6, 15, 2, 75)));
    }

    static final java.util.Random dice = new java.util.Random();
    private static final int[] NO_INTS = {};

   /** @param <code>nDraws</code> count of values to draw
    *  @param <code>from</code> lower bound for values
    *  @param <code>to_inclusive</code> upper bound for values
    *  @return sum of draws, excluding minimal value drawn */
    static int sumIgnoringMin(int nDraws, int from, int to_inclusive) {
        int to = to_inclusive - from + 1;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            sum = from * (nDraws);
        while (0 <= --nDraws) {
            int drawn = dice.nextInt(to);
            if (drawn < min)
                min = drawn;
            sum += drawn;
        }
        return sum - min - from;
    }
```

and stumbled upon not really knowing what representation to choose for the return value.
Oh, well, `int[]` and `Collection<Integer>` can be converted easily enough.
For lack of array rotation support, I went for a `Queue<Integer>`.

Comment: `sumIgnoringMin` could alternatively use `dice.ints(from, to_inclusive+1).limit(nDraws).summaryStatistics().getSum/Min()`.

Answer (score 1):

As already said by [greybeard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/238931/203649) you have to try to be more specific about efficiency and what you want to improve. Your code can be simplified , for example your `genAttribute()` method:

> ```
> public static int genAttribute() {
>         Random dice = new Random();
>         int[] sumArray = {dice.nextInt(6) + 1, dice.nextInt(6) + 1, dice.nextInt(6) + 1, dice.nextInt(6) + 1};
>         for (int num : sumArray) {
>             System.out.println(num);
>         }
>         //three cycles to obtain the three greatest elements omitted for brevity
>         System.out.println(first + " " + second + " " + third);
>         return first + second + third;
> }
> ```

You can use sort the array and loop over it in reverse, excluding the minimum element standing in the first position of the sorted array like below and avoiding the writing of three cycles for the three max elements:

```
public static int genAttribute() {
    Random dice = new Random();
    final int n = 4;
    int[] sumArray = dice.ints(n, 1, 7).toArray();

    for (int num : sumArray) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    Arrays.sort(sumArray);

    int sum = 0;
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        sum += sumArray[i];
        joiner.add(Integer.toString(sumArray[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(joiner);

    return sum;
}
```

I used the method [Random.ints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) to generate the array and after the [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class to print the elements. The code is using a parameter `n` that can be modified at your choice, so the code will remain the same even if the parameter `n` (number of dices) is modified.

A slight modification can be applied on your method `checkFinalArray`:

> ```
> public static boolean checkFinalArray(int[] checkArray) {
>     int fifteenCount = 0;
>     for (int z : checkArray) {
>          if (z >= 15) {
>               fifteenCount++;
>          }
>     }
>     return (fifteenCount >= 2 && Arrays.stream(checkArray).sum() >= 75);
> }
> ```

Obtain the sum of the elements directly in the array inside the cycle without using of stream at the end of the method:

```
public static boolean checkFinalArray(int[] checkArray) {
    int fifteenCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int z : checkArray) {
        if (z >= 15) {
            fifteenCount++;
        }
        sum += z;
    }
    return (fifteenCount >= 2 && sum >= 75);
}
```